# Django template looks up?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm looking for an explanation on the django tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) and especially the template part it says :

> The template system uses dot-lookup syntax to access variable attributes. In the example of `{{ question.question_text }}`, first Django does a dictionary lookup on the object question. Failing that, it tries an attribute lookup – which works, in this case. If attribute lookup had failed, it would’ve tried a list-index lookup.

How could it have a dictionary, attribute and list-index lookup on the Question object?
If my `Question` object holds a list, I will create an attribute `list` and set the value on it. So it's only going to be an attribute `lookup` ?
I think I didn't understand something...
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have one, but the template doesn't know that until it tries. The point the documentation is trying to make is that the template will try all three kinds of lookup, so that you can pass a dictionary, an object, or a list and access them in the same way.